# where is the regex engine located?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

We're covering sed in class and I was wondering about the way sed uses the regex engine. Does each program (sed, awk, grep, etc.) use a regex engine that was programmed into it, or is there a regex engine tool/library/function that the individuals developing sed, grep, etc. just implement in their code? Is the engine built into the OS and then called by the tools utilizing it? I feel like knowing this will help me understand the level of standardization regex has achieved.
Who made you, regex engine? Where is your source code?

Comment: Some programs use a common library (such as http://pcre.org), Some programs  contain their own regex  implementation. Yet others have a regex implementation that tries to emulate another regex implementation. And it's a mess.

Comment: The good thing about standards, they say, is there there are so many to choose from to fit your needs...  Even the well known `grep` understands more than one regex syntax, so there.  You cannot rely on regular expressions being handled exactly the same everywhere (regexes are ideas before being implementations), but understanding typical implementations will help you become proficient quickly on other variants, just like knowing how to program in one language helps you learn the next language more quickly.

Comment: See `man regcomp` and `man regexec` for docs on the C-library regex functionality shipped with your OS. On BSDs there's typically also a `man re_format`, or on GNU systems, `man 7 regex` to provide docs on the syntax your operating system's facilities (as opposed to various other implementations that might be installed by 3rd-party libraries or language runtimes) support.

Comment: BTW, some of those fancier regex versions provided by 3rd-party libraries are worse than traditional implementations by important objective measures. See https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Comment: Ha, yes @Fred. I actually googled today `Why does Microsoft have to be different?` out of frustration with their blaze-their-own-trail (sometimes, and less these days) attitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `sed` and `grep` by default understand the GNU Basic Regular Expressions notations which is an implementation of POSIX Basic Regular Expressions standard. POSIX is just a standard that Unix systems should subscribe to, but it can be implemented in any way.
Additionally, `sed` with `-r` and `grep` with `-e` or `egrep` understand the GNU Extended Regular Expression notation with their own implementation.
See http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html for both basic and extended regex details.

There is also `PCRE` and `PCRE2` which is Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. This is a complete library implemented in C/C++ and can be used as a standard implementation by other C/C++ software. PHP and `pgrep` use this. `grep` can also use this with `-P` provided `grep` has been compiled with PCRE support. (Not 100% sure, but I think `grep -P` just calls `pgrep` internally in this case.)
You can read details of those at http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html and http://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre2.html

Other than these, many languages and tools have their own regex engine. Perl, Python, Java, JavaScript, SQL databases all have their own regex implementations or borrow from other implementations. While they share the same concept, their notations and implementations can be drastically different. http://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html has a list of many software that implement regex.

To answer some specific questions you asked:

OSes do not implement any regex engine in the kernel. Regex implementation has nothing to do with hardware and does not require any kind of protection, resource management or low-level access which is what OS kernels deal with mostly. So there is no need for kernel to intervene.

Regex engine and source codes will vary across implementations. You can get the source code by digging into the regex specific module of the software source code, if it is available. But there's no "one ring to rule them all".

A good way to start would be to familiarize yourself with one regex implementation. GNU Extended is a good place to start since it is shared by `sed`, `grep` and `awk`. The source code for that is available in the Gnulib at http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib. After that, you can try learning more advanced features of other implementations.

Hope this helps!

Comment: POSIX.2 *does* require that a compliant OS ship regex functionality (as in its standard C library), so I'm not sure that the statement that operating systems don't provide a regex engine is entirely accurate. For GNU's implementation, I'd argue that the more canonical is https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html -- not gnulib (GPLed software, intended to provide GNU extensions on non-GNU platforms) but glibc (LGPLed, superset of libc-mandated functionality).

Comment: I should have clarified in the answrr that by OS, I meant as part of the kernel. Even grep and sed are part of the core OS components!

Comment: Sure. I didn't read the OP to mean kernel when they said "OS", but there's certainly ambiguity there, and it's helpful to clarify.

Comment: Gnulib is just a central repository of common GNU code. glibc and gnulib have the same regex implementation and regex module is LGPL'd (http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob_plain;f=modules/regex). Gnulib is mostly to allow for development of software using GNU extensions on non-GNU systems.

Comment: Thank you for the correction re: gnulib's licensing.